# continuous and periodic function such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.

Tags: functions, continuity, periodic-functions

$f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}, $ f continuous.
$f(0)=f(2\pi)$
Show that there exists an $x_0\in(0,\pi)$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x_0+\pi)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Consider $g:[0, \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as $g(t) = f(t) - f(t+\pi)$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Perhaps add a hint to look at the signs of $g(0)$ and $g(\pi)$ and observe that $g(0)=-g(\pi)$.